# Laravel 5 model relationship many to many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the following table setup:

countries (id)

languages (id)

country_languages (id, country_id, language_id)

In plain SQL I can fetch all countries with their corresponding language(s) fairly easily:

```
SELECT * FROM countries

INNER JOIN country_languages
    ON country_languages.country_id = countries.id

INNER JOIN languages
    ON languages.id = country_languages.language_id;
```

In Laravel (5), using the following works:

In Country model:

```
public function countryLanguages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('CountryLanguage');
}
```

In CountryLanguage Model:

```
public function language()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Language');
}
```

`$countries = Country::with('countryLanguages.language');`

I'd like have a single relationship method `languages` however that can be called directly on the `Country` model. Is this possible? I've tried the `hasManyThrough` and other methods but so far no luck!

Comment: You don't need to create  a CountryLanguage Model for many to many relationships. Check the corresponding section in the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: you are talking about many to many relations , but you are implementing one to many

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to geondri for pushing me in the right direction.
This is what I ended up with which is a lot easier than I could possibly imagine:

```
public function languages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Language', CountryLanguage::getTableName());
}
```